# May I ask question about identifying of foreigner's name?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I heard some person's name, who's is foreigner for me and did quiet sure that I heard it right because couldn't find it on the Internet. So I would like to ask what name there are similar to what I heard.

Comment: The "name facts" forum on this site https://www.behindthename.com/ is probably useful. Try to search the name in the database first, there is some fuzzy matching implemented on that site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the question is not about linguistics, it would be unsuitable for this site.

Here are the general guidelines:
[What topics can I ask about here?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)